# How to let swift compile basic math in reasonable time

Tags: swift, performance, math, compilation

```
func molasses(x:Double) -> Double {
    return 1 - abs(x * 6 - floor(x * 3) * 2 - 1)
}
```

That expression takes over 10 seconds to compile in Xcode 11.  Why does it take so long?  This is just one line in a larger algorithm.  How can I make it faster without cluttering up the code?

Comment: Try changing all of the integer constants to doubles like `1` to `1.0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under the current implementation, Swift is not good at inferring types when some generic or overloaded functions (including operators) are used in combination.

So, this would improve the compile time:

```
func molasses(x:Double) -> Double {
    let f = floor(x * 3) * 2
    let a = abs(x * 6 - f - 1)
    return 1 - a
}
```

(You may think this as sort of *cluttering up*...)

Or, using some type-specific (non-generic, non-overloaded) functions would do as well:

```
func dfloor(_ x: Double)->Double {floor(x)}

func molasses(x:Double) -> Double {
    return 1 - fabs(x * 6 - dfloor(x * 3) * 2 - 1)
}
```